# truncate a string in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, truncate

I have a string like this in bash: `*_*_*_*` where * could be any number of letters, numbers, and legal characters.
I need to truncate the string to `*_*`.

An example is: 00001_99_AA_FLLLA -----> 00001_99

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: None of the answers link to the [docs to truncate string in variable](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#:~:text=parameter%23) so here it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter expansion:

```
while [[ $string = *_*_* ]] ; do
    string=${string%_*}
done
```

- `${string%_*}` removes the last _ and whatever follows it from $string
- we do it while $string contains at least two underscores

Answer (score 2):

If `s` is your string, try:

```
x=_${s#*_*_}
s=${s%$x}
```

This approach has two advantages: (1) it requires no loops which should make it fast, and (2) it is POSIX and therefore portable to any POSIX-compatible shell.

#### Example

```
$ s=00001_99_AA_FLLLA
$ x=_${s#*_*_}; s=${s%$x}
$ echo "$s"
00001_99
```

#### How it works

This code works in two steps: first we find the string that we want to remove from `s` and then we remove it.  In more detail:

1. `x=_${s#*_*_}`

   This sets `x` to the string that we want to remove from `s`.  `${s#*_*_}` removes from `s` the shortest string that contains two underscores.  `_${s#*_*_}` puts an underscore in front of that 
   string.  Using our example:

```
    $ s=00001_99_AA_FLLLA; echo "_${s#*_*_}"
    _AA_FLLLA
```

2. `s=${s%$x}`

   This removes `$x` from the end of string `s`.  This gives us what we are looking for.  Using our example:

```
    $ echo "${s%$x}"
    00001_99
```

Comment: I see that we have all, both OP and the 2 answers, had a visit from the anonymous downvoter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I can't vote for your answer but that worked for me. Just a quick question: Why x=${s#*_*_} returns AA_FLLLA and not 00001_99? It's not clear to me how it works.

Comment: @user3708408  There is a distinction between `#` which signals prefix removal and `%` which signals suffix removal. `${s#*_*_}` _removes_ from the beginning of `s`.  By contrast, `${s%_*_*}` _removes_ from the end of `s`.  That is why  `${s#*_*_} ` returns `AA_FLLLA` and not `00001_99`.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings you want to truncate are in a file called `myfile.txt`, in bash, you can always do:

```
cut -d_ -f1,2 myfile.txt
```

The first option `-d_` will specify the underscore as the delimiting character, and the second option `-f1,2` specifies that you want fields 1 and 2 (only) returned.

So, you could write the output to another file like this:

```
cut -d_ -f1,2 myfile.txt > output.txt
```